# A basic probability question on uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that independent trials, each of which is equally likely to have any of $m$ possible outcomes, are performed until the same outcome occurs $k$ consecutive times. If $N$ denotes the number of trials, then it has been found that one observed value of $N$ is approximately 0.78 standard deviations less than $E[N]$. Now it is said that this information is quite consistent with the uniformity assumption of each outcome. How ? This statement is from "introduction to probability models" by sheldon ross. Chapter 3 excercise 22

Comment: Looks like total gibberish to me. No matter what the random variable $N$ is (except most degenerate or exotic distributions), observing something within about one standard deviation from the mean on either side is totally unsurprising.

Comment: @fedja, let's be civil please.

Comment: What is total gibberish? I thought this question was remarkably clear.

Comment: Although expressed in non-standard language I think the OP is basically asking about hypothesis testing. In other words, the null hypothesis is that outcomes are equally likely and I observed a sample data point according to some experimental protocol. Can I reject my null?

Comment: A basic request: begin to accept some basic answers to the basic questions you asked when these basic answers basically satisfy you.

Comment: @vadim123 I refer not to the OP's presentation of the question but to the statement itself (which, as far as I understand, is an exercise from the book or the homework). Unless the terminology there is very unusual, I just cannot assign any meaningful sense to that statement. Indeed, assume that the outcome distribution was very far from uniform. Would it make the observation less probable? Not at all! I'll check the book to try to figure out what was meant.

Comment: Checked it. Ross or his publishers are zealous about copyright so it took 6 minutes to find the book online instead of the usual 1. All I can say now is: if you don't understand how to solve a problem, *post the question in full*, not the first 3 and the last 2 lines of a 19 line paragraph skipping everything in the middle and making the question totally incomprehensible!

Comment: @Zen Oh yeah? $ $